# build-impl.xml:913 Execution failed with error code 1 J2ME

Tags: java, java-me

I have problems with J2ME I used x32 java, when I run this I have Error

Root/NetBeansProjects\mApp2\nbproject\build-impl.xml:913: Execution failed with error code 1.

```
   <nb-run jadfile="${dist.dir}/${dist.jad}" jarfile="${dist.dir}/${dist.jar}" jadurl="${dist.jad.url}" device="${platform.device}" platformhome="${platform.home}" platformtype="${platform.type}" execmethod="${run.method}" securitydomain="${evaluated.run.security.domain}" commandline="${platform.runcommandline}" classpath="${platform.bootclasspath}:${dist.dir}/${dist.jar}" cmdoptions="${run.cmd.options}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have windows 7 - 64 bit & I had this problem "Execution failed with error code 1". 
It is there for reasons like

1. Emulator not configured
2. SDK not installed
3. (OR may be other reasons which i am not aware of)

So i just installed Java ME SDK 3.4 ([Download Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/download/sdk/index.html)) - 32 bit & plugins all available & I m good to go.